# page doesn't work after moving files (and changing the src)

Tags: html, angularjs

There are similar questions like mine, but they couldn't help me out.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test-Site</title>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/App_Data/mainApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Controllers/testController.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="~/App_Data/mainApp" ng-    controller="~/Controllers/testController">
    Write your Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name.firstName" />

    Your Name: {{name.firstName}}
</div>
```

**main.app.js:**

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
```

**test.controller.js:**

```
mainApp.controller("testController", function ($scope) {
$scope.name = { firstName: "Peter" };
});
```

**Chrome console gives me following errors:**
Test.html:8 GET http://localhost:55835/~/Controllers/testController.js 
Test.html:7 GET http://localhost:55835/~/App_Data/mainApp.js 
angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ~/App_Data/mainApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '~/App_Data/mainApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Everything was fine, until I moved the js-files into their folders.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the server side path `~/` in a client side page.  You cannot use the server side path in this way.  You need to provide the full path from the root of the site to your files; most likely, just removing the `~/` will be enough.

As a side note, normally the `App_Data` folder is for things like Database files and other server resources; it seems an odd place to put your `mainApp.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. controller="~/Controllers/testController" was also wrong. correct would be: ng-controller="testController". But it seems my mainApp.js file is only working outside, like ng-app="mainApp" (not inside any folder). How can I make that work?